# SQL change day in my language in select statement

Tags: sql, vb.net

How  can I change the day in my language with a select statement like use if:

```
if day= sunday then set day = minggu
```

Comment: Question not clear. And yet, of you need to update a DAY column in all records you can use a construct like `update tablename set columnname = 'minggu' where columnname = 'sunday'`. If you need to do it for all 7 days of the week (and it is a one-time conversion), repeat the above for each day (you could use a `case` but will make things much more complex).

Comment: thx man for solution i just do simple  update my column afther insert like u do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of conversion. Take a look at example below:

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (GETDATE()),
    (DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())),
    (DATEADD(DAY, 2, GETDATE())),
    (DATEADD(DAY, 3, GETDATE())),
    (DATEADD(DAY, 4, GETDATE())),
    (DATEADD(DAY, 5, GETDATE())),
    (DATEADD(DAY, 6, GETDATE()))
    ) T(Dates)
)
SELECT
    FORMAT(Dates, 'ddd', 'id-ID') LocalizedFormat,
    SUBSTRING('MingguSen   Sel   Rabu  Kamis Jumat Sabtu ', 6*(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Dates)-1)+1, 6) LocalizedExpression
FROM Src
```

It results in:

```
LocalizedFormat     LocalizedExpression
---------------     -------------------
Kamis               Kamis 
Jumat               Jumat 
Sabtu               Sabtu 
Minggu              Minggu
Sen                 Sen   
Sel                 Sel   
Rabu                Rabu
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an update statement? Because you have a SET in your select statement. If so, how about this?

```
UPDATE table_name
SET datecol = CASE
    WHEN DATENAME(dw, datecol) = 'Monday' THEN 'Minggu'
    WHEN DATENAME(dw, datecol) = 'Tuesday' 
    ...
    ELSE datecol
END;
```